Python Package Bug on installing via conda
I attempted conda install on a remote pc from my university.
Attempted
conda install pytorch==2.2.0 torchvision==0.17.0 pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia -y
It is very slow and I am unable to install from it. It gives the following error.
Can anybody help on looking at the error? I installed miniconda from the official website by command line.
Here's the bug:
CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/ATen/templates/RegisterDispatchKey.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/ATen/templates/RegisterFunctionalization.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/ATen/templates/RegisterSchema.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/ATen/templates/TensorMethods.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/ATen/templates/UfuncCPU.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/ATen/templates/UfuncCPUKernel.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/ATen/templates/UfuncCUDA.cu'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/ATen/templates/UnboxingFunctions.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/README.md'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/build.bzl'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/ADInplaceOrViewType.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/Functions.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/TraceType.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/VariableType.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/annotated_fn_args.py.in'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/python_enum_tag.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/python_fft_functions.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/python_functions.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/python_linalg_functions.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/python_nested_functions.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/python_nn_functions.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/python_return_types.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/python_sparse_functions.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/python_special_functions.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/python_torch_functions.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at /home/wang.ziyue7/miniconda3/pkgs/pytorch-2.2.0-py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen/packaged/autograd/templates/python_variable_methods.cpp'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/linux-64::jpeg-9e-h5eee18b_3, pytorch/linux-64::libjpeg-turbo-2.0.0-h9bf148f_0
  path: 'bin/cjpeg'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/linux-64::jpeg-9e-h5eee18b_3, pytorch/linux-64::libjpeg-turbo-2.0.0-h9bf148f_0
  path: 'bin/djpeg'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/linux-64::jpeg-9e-h5eee18b_3, pytorch/linux-64::libjpeg-turbo-2.0.0-h9bf148f_0
  path: 'bin/jpegtran'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/linux-64::jpeg-9e-h5eee18b_3, pytorch/linux-64::libjpeg-turbo-2.0.0-h9bf148f_0
  path: 'bin/rdjpgcom'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/linux-64::jpeg-9e-h5eee18b_3, pytorch/linux-64::libjpeg-turbo-2.0.0-h9bf148f_0
  path: 'bin/wrjpgcom'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/linux-64::jpeg-9e-h5eee18b_3, pytorch/linux-64::libjpeg-turbo-2.0.0-h9bf148f_0
  path: 'include/jconfig.h'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/linux-64::jpeg-9e-h5eee18b_3, pytorch/linux-64::libjpeg-turbo-2.0.0-h9bf148f_0
  path: 'include/jerror.h'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/linux-64::jpeg-9e-h5eee18b_3, pytorch/linux-64::libjpeg-turbo-2.0.0-h9bf148f_0
  path: 'include/jmorecfg.h'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/linux-64::jpeg-9e-h5eee18b_3, pytorch/linux-64::libjpeg-turbo-2.0.0-h9bf148f_0
  path: 'include/jpeglib.h'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/linux-64::jpeg-9e-h5eee18b_3, pytorch/linux-64::libjpeg-turbo-2.0.0-h9bf148f_0
  path: 'lib/libjpeg.a'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/linux-64::jpeg-9e-h5eee18b_3, pytorch/linux-64::libjpeg-turbo-2.0.0-h9bf148f_0
  path: 'lib/libjpeg.so'


There are two issues associated with your post:

Corrupted Package Files: The CondaVerificationError suggests some files expected within Pytorch are either missing or corrupted. It is either the package installation process was interrupted or incorrectly downloaded.
Path Conflict: The error ClobberError suggest that there is an issue with the file path used. Such error occurs when two try to install files to the same location. In this case the conflict is between jpeg and lipjpeg-turbo, both of which want to use the bin and include folders or directories.

Please take the following steps to resolve the issues:

Clear conda package cache to remove potentially corrupted files.
Use the code (bash):
conda clean --all

To ensure that you using the latest version of conda, use the update Conda using this code (bash):
conda update conda
This is likely to fix the compatibility issues.

Attempt the installation again by reinstalling with the original command. This is the code: conda install pytorch==2.2.0 torchvision==0.17.0 pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia


